# How to block pop-up windows with Selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Pop up windows are messing up a web scrapper that I am trying to create using selenium/python. The goal is to extract text from every sub-page of a webpage. However, at random instances this pop-up window appears:
[image]

I tried to eliminate pop up windows from the options of the webdriver, but it does not work. Here is the code for the chrome instance:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If the popup appears at a specific point of time you can close the popup clicking on the <kbd>X</kbd> element. However, if the popup springs up randomly, it would be difficult to be handled using [selenium-webdriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver).

An easier and ideal approach would be to ask the developers/devops team to **disable** the popup in the testing environment for the sake of automated tests.

Answer (score 0):

- This isn't a pop-up window, it's more like a "Toast" (that's why the
  option `options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")` isn't gonna
  work).
- You can close it or even better delete it but the server could render
  a new one.
- You can try removing the element (sending some javascript) hoping the
  server doesn't render a new one. If the server renders a new one you
  can try removing it again.
- to locate the element you should look up for a few lines (father
  elements) above.

---

Try using one of these:

### Script by Id

```
js = """
element = document.getElementById("your id");
element.remove();
"""
```

### Script By Classes

```
js = """
element = document.getElementsByClassName("your classes");
element[0].remove()
"""
```

---

Then Execute the script

### Execute Script

```
driver.execute_script(js)
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle pop-up windows using Selenium and Python, you can use the WebDriverWait class along with the expected conditions provided by Selenium. By waiting for the pop-up window to appear and then handling it, you can continue with your automation script.

```
# Wait for the pop-up window to appear
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
    
    # Switch to the pop-up window
    windows = driver.window_handles
    driver.switch_to.window(windows[1])

    # Close the pop-up window
    driver.close()
    
    # Switch back to the main window (if needed)
    driver.switch_to.window(windows[0])
```